# Selecting numpy array elements

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have the task of selecting p% of elements within a given numpy array. For example,

```
# Initialize 5 x 3 array-
x = np.random.randint(low = -10, high = 10, size = (5, 3))

x
'''
array([[-4, -8,  3],
       [-9, -1,  5],
       [ 9,  1,  1],
       [-1, -1, -5],
       [-1, -4, -1]])
'''
```

Now, I want to select say p = 30% of the numbers in `x`, so 30% of numbers in `x` is 5 (rounded up).

Is there a way to select these 30% of numbers in `x`? Where `p` can change and the dimensionality of numpy array `x` can be 3-D or maybe more.

I am using Python 3.7 and numpy 1.18.1

Thanks

Comment: What shape do you expect for the output array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.random.choice` to sample without replacement from a 1d numpy array:

```
p = 0.3
np.random.choice(x.flatten(), int(x.size * p) , replace=False)
```

For large arrays, the performance of sampling without replacement can be pretty bad, but there are some [workarounds](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2764).

Answer (score 0):

You can randome choice `0,1` and use`np.nonzero` and boolean indexing:

```
np.random.seed(1)
x[np.nonzero(np.random.choice([1, 0], size=x.shape, p=[0.3,0.7]))]
```

Output:

```
array([ 3, -1,  5,  9, -1, -1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of selecting p% of numpy elements:

```
p = 20

# To select p% of elements-
x_abs[x_abs < np.percentile(x_abs, p)]

# To select p% of elements and set them to a value (in this case, zero)-
x_abs[x_abs < np.percentile(x_abs, p)] = 0
```